# Having problem to connect with mongodb to node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, database, mongodb

[image: Screenshot of the node.js file & error]

Having problem in locating the path in node.js file.

if you see the screenshot in line2 i written  **require('./db/conn');** But it is showing Error: **Cannot find module './db/conn'**. please give a solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 1):

your `app.js` file is located under `models` folder,

so either move file`src/models/app.js` -> `src/app.js` or

change that statement to `require('../db/conn');`.